# SQL apply sum avg conditionally

Tags: sql, sum, sybase, average

Supposed we have the following table:

```
index  value
1      55  
2      66  
3      77  
1      88  
3      99
```

how can i sum(value) when index=1 or index=3, and avg(value) when index=2 in one select statement?

Comment: What is your expected result (in table format)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily:

```
SELECT index, CASE WHEN index IN (1, 3) THEN SUM(value) ELSE AVG(value) END
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY index
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(value) as agg,
       'S' as aggregateType
FROM DaTAble
WHERE index IN (1, 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT avg(value) as agg,
       'A' as aggregateType
FROM DaTAble
WHERE index = 2
```